# Match reverse translation of a capture group in Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl, reverse, tr

I am trying to find strings that match a certain pattern and then the reverse translation of that pattern followed by it separated by a letter O.

Translation rule is **/ABC/XYZ**.

Example of a match: CCBAOXYZZ

First section matches the pattern [ABC]{3,25}. Then there's a letter `O` which also matches. Then we see that XYZZ is the reverse of CCBA with the translation above applied.

I have managed to write the tr rule into my backreferencing. But I cannot figure out how to do the reverse as well.

```
while (my $input_string = <sample_input>) {
    push @hit, $1 while $input_string
        =~ m{
          (([ABC]{3,25})
          O
          (??{ $2 =~ tr/ABC/XYZ/r}))
        }xg;
}
```

Is it correct to add the 'reverse' function to the third line of the regex in this way: `(??{ $2 =~ tr/ACGT/TGCA/r;reverse}))`?

How do I match the `reverse tr` of $2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `tr///r` *returns* the transliterated string. So you simply need to stick your `reverse` in front of the `tr///r` and you're good to go.

```
push @hit, $1 while $input_string
    =~ m{
      (([ABC]{3,25})
      O
      (??{ reverse $2 =~ tr/ABC/XYZ/r }))
    }xg;
```

The return value of the `tr///r` does not go into `$_`, so `; reverse` will reverse whatever is in `$_`. That makes the overall match fail.

You actually answered your own question in your last sentence.

> How do I do the match the reverse tr of $2?

---

If you [add `use re 'debug'`](http://perldoc.perl.org/re.html#'debug'-mode) you can see the actual pattern that is being matched against.

With `tr///; reverse`, the second part of that debugging output, which relates to the regex compiled from the `eval`, is:

```
...
Compiling REx "ZZYXOABCC"
Final program:
   1: EXACT <ZZYXOABCC> (5)
   5: END (0)
anchored "ZZYXOABCC" at 0 (checking anchored isall) minlen 9 
Matching embedded REx "ZZYXOABCC" against "XYZZ"
...
```

As we can see here, it took the full string as the second part of the match, after the `O`. It correctly reversed the left side of the string, but it returned the full string.

Now if we compare that to `reverse tr///r`, we see the difference.

```
...
Compiling REx "XYZZ"
Final program:
   1: EXACT <XYZZ> (3)
   3: END (0)
anchored "XYZZ" at 0 (checking anchored isall) minlen 4 
Matching embedded REx "XYZZ" against "XYZZ"
...
```

It now only returns the transliterated left side of the string, which then matches.